# Enum class method gives nullpointer

Tags: java, enums

Hey I am trying to work with an enum class, but this class keeps giving me nullpointers if I try to call the getLocation method... Any one knows what is up?

Enum class:

```
    public enum ZulrahLocation {

    CENTER(ZulrahScript.TILE_CENTER),
    WEST(ZulrahScript.TILE_WEST),
    SOUTH(ZulrahScript.TILE_SOUTH),
    EAST(ZulrahScript.TILE_EAST);

    private InstanceTile location;

    ZulrahLocation(final InstanceTile location)
    {
    this.location = location;
    }

    public Position getLocation()
    {
        return location.toTile();
    }
    }
```

Class that loops through enum class: nullpointer at the log z1.getlocation()

```
     for (ZulrahLocation zl : ZulrahLocation.values())
     {
     sI.log(String.valueOf(zl.getLocation()) + " Location of z1");
     }
```

If somebody is wondering I am setting all the tiles in the main class which happens here:

```
    public void onStart () {
    TILE_CENTER                 = new InstanceTile(164, 99, 0,this);
    TILE_WEST                   = new InstanceTile(154, 97, 0,this);
    TILE_SOUTH                  = new InstanceTile(164, 88, 0,this);
    TILE_EAST                   = new InstanceTile(174, 97, 0,this);
    }
```

If you need additional information please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

When your program first starts, the `ZulrahLocation` enum values are initialized with the current values of your `ZulrahScript` tiles. Because you are defining them in a method (`onStart`) that needs to be called, the initial values that are used are actually `null`.

In your `ZulrahScript` class, you may want to declare and define the variables on the same line.

```
public class ZulrahScript {
    ...
    public static InstanceTile TILE_CENTER = new InstanceTile(164, 99, 0,this);
    ...
}
```

Comment: This makes sense but I still have a problem if I do this. public static InstanceTile TILE_CENTER = new InstanceTile(164, 99, 0,this); will give an error on this which says: ZulrahScript.this cannot be referenced from a static context. You probaly would say delete the static but then CENTER(ZulrahScript.TILE_CENTER) while say it needs to be static... any way to solve this?